# "Поздравить коллег по работе с праздником" — есть ли ошибка?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

***Он поздравил коллег по работе с праздником.***

Какая лексическая ошибка присутствует в данном выражении?

Comment: Похоже на д/з, а их мы не выполняем. От автора вопроса требуется показать, что он самостоятельно пытался решить проблему, и указать, в чем он затрудняется.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это д/з

Comment: Ну зачем закрывать-то? Все ли голосовавшие за его закрытие смогут ответить аргументированно ответить на этот вопрос?

Comment: Я согласилась с Вами и отозвала свой голос "за закрытие". Да, есть о чём и куда пораскинуть...

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, по-моему, Вы сделали то, против чего возражали недавно: изменили суть вопроса. (1) Автор был уверен, что ошибка есть. (2) Автор рассматривал все предложение в целом, а не его часть.

Comment: Есть, есть такое дело! Исправлюсь — вмиг.

Answer (score 4):

> ***Он поздравил коллег по работе с праздником.***
>
> Какая лексическая ошибка присутствует в данном выражении?

Этот пример присутствует во многих учебных заданиях. По мнению составителей этих заданий (и авторов ряда словарей) ошибка здесь — тавтологичность сочетания ***коллега по работе***.

Но можно ли в отсутствие контекста однозначно квалифицировать такое сочетание как ошибку? По-моему, нет.

Если бы коллегами назывались только товарищи по работе, то да, такое сочетание было бы избыточно. Но коллегами ведь называют и товарищей по партии, по специальности, по совместной учёбе…

В словаре-справочнике "Трудности русского языка" под ред. Рахмановой (В.Н. Вакуров и др. "Трудности…",4-е издание, переработанное; М., 2011) говорится:

> В значении слова ***коллега*** уже содержится указание на то, что это
>   лицо одинаковой с кем-либо специальности, товарищ по работе, поэтому
>   сочетания ***коллега по труду, коллега по работе, коллега по
>   специальности*** тавтологичны, а слова ***по труду, по работе, по
>   специальности*** в таких сочетаниях избыточны, ненужны…

В то же время:

> Сочетания ***коллега по труду, коллега по работе*** и т. д.
>   оправданны, если содержат необходимое по условиям сообщения уточнение
>   того, о каком именно лице идёт речь — об учившемся где-либо вместе с
>   кем-либо, о работающем в таком-то месте (как и кто-либо другой) или о
>   занимающемся таким-то родом деятельности.

Но как в отсутствие контекста определить, нужно ли какое-либо дополнительное уточнение к сочетанию ***коллега по работе?*** Ведь и  *по работе* можно считать уточнением в слову *коллега*, если речь идёт о человеке,  имеющем  коллег не только *по работе*.

Не считает ошибкой сочетание ***коллега по работе*** и "Словарь грамматической сочетаемости слов русского языка" (Лазуткина Е.М. "Словарь…", М., 2013), выпущенный в рамках программы "Словари  XXI века". Пример из словаря:

***Коллега по работе*** советует мне не брать кредит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

**КОЛЛЕГА** -и; *м*. и *ж*. [лат. collega]
Товарищ по работе, по совместной учёбе (в высшей школе), по профессии.
*Мы с вами коллеги. Коллега Петров выступит с докладом на следующем заседании. Коллега, повторите, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос.*
Большой толковый словарь русского языка Кузнецова

**колле́га** -и, *м.* и *ж. книжн.*
Товарищ по работе, по совместной учебе (в высшей школе), по профессии.
*— Мы ведь с вами [следователем] немножко коллеги. Когда-то я был товарищем прокурора* (Чехов. По делам службы).
*— Позвольте представить. Мефодий Силыч, сотрудник студии Цветухина. Так сказать, **коллега** моей дочери **по театральному поприщу*** (Федин. Необыкновенное лето).
[**Малый академический словарь**](https://gufo.me/dict/mas/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0)

**КОЛЛЕГА,** -и, *м.* и *ж*.
Товарищ по учению или работе (о работниках умственного труда, о квалифицированных специалистах) **[неправильно употреблять коллега по чему-нибудь, например, коллега по работе].**
[**Толковый словарь Ожегова и Шведовой**](https://gufo.me/dict/ozhegov/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0)

Итак, мы имеем два взаимоисключающих (словарных) мнения:
Ожегов и Шведова говорят, что "неправильно употреблять коллега по чему-нибудь", а МАС приводит пример употребления "коллега... по театральному поприщу".

Мне кажется, что употребление словосочетания "коллега по..." возможно в том случае, когда речь идёт о разъяснении, уточнении, конкретизации: ***кого именно*** из коллег говорящий имеет ввиду (из вместе учащихся, работающих, танцующих, поющих, имеющих общее хобби или эксклюзивное увлечение...).

Comment: Я согласен с точкой зрения, что слово "коллега" можно употреблять с уточнениями (без добавлений оно воспринимается как "товарищ по профессии", что гораздо шире). Но сама возможность уточнений выявляет не совсем удачный порядок слов в предложении. Формально можно допустить, что некие сотрудники   "работали с праздником" (по указанию директора украшали к Новому году офисы) и в этом они - временные "коллеги". Исключить такое прочтение можно изменением порядка слов: Он поздравил с праздником коллег по работе.

Comment: Формально и после изменения порядка слов есть неоднозначность (можно здесь увидеть *праздник колег по работе*)

Comment: Думаю, автор вопроса (а первоначально вопрос был не о том, есть ли ошибка, а о том, где она) имел в виду версию Ожегова.

Comment: Может, стоит вернуться к первоначальному виду предложения? Я-то хотела _как лучше_.

Answer (score 1):

"Он поздравил коллег по работе с праздником". Ошибка фразеологическая. Возникла в результате  ассоциации с выражением "товарищи по работе".

Существительное "коллеги", в отличие от слова "товарищи" не допускает при себе управляемого слова.

Надо: "Он поздравил коллег с праздником". Или: "Он поздравил товарищей по работе с праздником".

Comment: Предложение - не простое для диагностики. Возможны различные варианты (ход мысли): плеоназм, двусмысленность.. Поэтому я  решился, все-таки, ответить.

Comment: _Борис Бобылев: Существительное "коллеги", в отличие от слова "товарищи" не допускает при себе управляемого слова._ ===  Иногда допускает.

Comment: Приведите пример.

Comment: Пример: _По принятому в России этикету форма обращения на "ты" используется **к  коллегам по работе**, находящимся в неофициальных отношениях друг с другом._  https://books.google.ru/books?id=0YsyDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT59&dq=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%22+%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDoICK2r7XAhVQ5KQKHaAHDqUQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%22%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&f=false

Comment: В пушкинском "Путешествии в Арзрум" калмычка на вопрос заигрывающего поэта: "Красавица, что ты шьешь? - отвечала кокетливо: - Портка шьем.- Кому? - Себя."  Увы, авторы пособий по культуре речи тоже могут "шить портка себя" :)

Comment: Ну а каким авторам и каким пособиям Вы лично доверяете? Постараюсь найти и привести примеры оттуда.

Comment: Н.М. Шанский, Е.М. Галкина-Федорук,  А.Н. Гвоздев, Л.К Граудина, М.Р. Львов, Л.И. Скворцов, Д.Э. Розенталь, Б.С.Мучник, И.Б. Голуб.